# Boundary in AdS / CFT correspondence

Tags: string-theory, coordinate-systems, observers, ads-cft, holographic-principle

In AdS / CFT correspondence, the boundary with 2D conformal field theory refers to the observer who is at the center of the 3D AdS space. What will happen when the coordinates of the observer change? Will the new location of the observer correspond to a different quantum field at the new boundary, or is it a different state of the same quantum field? In other words, do different coordinates of an observer in AdS space correspond to different quantum fields defined on different two-dimensional boundaries, or are they different states of the same field?

Comment: No. The boundary is infinitely far away so any finite shift in the position of a bulk observer does not modify the boundary itself. It does modify the boundary operators that correspond to the measurements that the bulk observer makes.

Comment: @Prahar That is, the same quantum field is on the boundary. Thank you!